# R: manipulate elements of complex list with function

Tags: r

I am stuck doing some manipulations on a list. This list is an output of ga_account_list() from the googleAnalyticsR library.

Here is a sample of the list (first two elements). I called it ga_goals:

```
List of 2
 $ :List of 6
  ..$ kind        : chr "analytics#goals"
  ..$ username    : chr "1234@abcd.de"
  ..$ totalResults: int 9
  ..$ startIndex  : int 1
  ..$ itemsPerPage: int 1000
  ..$ items       :'data.frame':    9 obs. of  15 variables:
  .. ..$ id                   : chr [1:9] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. ..$ kind                 : chr [1:9] "analytics#goal" "analytics#goal" "analytics#goal" "analytics#goal" ...
  .. ..$ selfLink             : chr [1:9] "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/46324974/w

......

$ :List of 6
  ..$ kind        : chr "analytics#goals"
  ..$ username    : chr "1234@abcd.de"
  ..$ totalResults: int 8
  ..$ startIndex  : int 1
  ..$ itemsPerPage: int 1000
  ..$ items       :'data.frame':    8 obs. of  15 variables:
  .. ..$ id                   : chr [1:8] "2" "3" "4" "5" ...
  .. ..$ kind                 : chr [1:8] "analytics#goal" "analytics#goal" "analytics#goal" "analytics#goal" ...
  .. ..$ selfLink             : chr [1:8] "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/46324974/w
```

What I'd like to do is to write a function that removes some elements of this list. For example I'd like to remove the "kind" and "username" fields.

I have tried to leverage r functional programming capabilities by writing a function that I could apply to the ga_goals list. But it did not work.

Here is the function and the call to it:

```
clean_goal_list <- function(goal_list){

 goal_list[["kind"]] <- NULL

}

map(ga_goals, clean_goal_list)
```

Running this returnst the following output:

```
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL
```

And the original list stays unchanged.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Return the changed value at the end: `clean_goal_list <- function(goal_list){; goal_list[["b"]] <- NULL; goal_list; }`.

Answer (score 1):

I've finally figured out myself why my approach did not work.

My error was that I thought that I could manipulate ga_goals directly by using it as an argument of the map function. What I do know is ceating a coply of this list inside the function and return the manipulated list as the output of the function.

My second mistake was the attempt to adress the list elements (inside the function) with goal_list[["kind"]]. This did not work. I tried goal_list$kind and this works as expected.